# Simple Python 3 addition game

Tags: python

I am coding a simple maths game in Python that gets user input to a addition question until they get it correct

this is the code I tried:

```
import random


def problem():
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)

    while user_solution != solution:
        get_user_solution(problem)
        
    if user_solution == solution:
        print('You are correct')
        
        
def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result

problem()
```

It seems to work if the user inputs the correct answer immediately, or when the user inputs an incorrect answer, but not if the user first inputs an incorrect answer then the correct one as shown below

[image]

Comment: You forgot to reassign the user's answer: `user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)` in the `while` loop

Comment: Also, watch out for naming a function and its variable with the same name. Not the best practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your while loop, when you call on the function get_user_problem(problem) you are not updating user_solution to the answer that the user inputs. The answer you keep checking against is the first time that the user inputs anything because that is what you have stored in user_solution and if that is not a correct answer, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Moreover, you don't need the last conditional because it only exits the while loop if your user inputs the right answer so you don't have to check that again!

Here is your corrected code:

```py
import random


def problem():
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)

    while user_solution != solution:
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        #you could add some feedback here and say "incorrect answer"
        
    print("You are correct!")
        
        
def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result

"""
you could also house this call in a if __name__ == '__main__': conditional, look it up, may help in the future!
"""
problem()
```

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the assignment to the variable inside the `while` loop:

```py
import random

def problem():
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)

    while user_solution != solution:
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        
    if user_solution == solution:
        print('You are correct')
               
def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result

problem()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


def problem():
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
    
    while True:
        if get_user_solution(problem) == solution:
            print('You are correct')
            break
        
        
def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result

problem()
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the user_solution value inside the while loop.

```
import random
    
 
def problem():
    number_one = random.randrange(1, 21)
    number_two = random.randrange(1, 21)
    problem = str(number_one) + " + " + str(number_two)
    solution = number_one + number_two
    user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)

    while user_solution != solution:
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)#you want to update the value of user_solution
        
    #if user_solution == solution: that is useless because only if while loop is completed,comes to this step
    print('You are correct')
        
        
def get_user_solution(problem):
    print("Enter your answer")
    print(problem, end="")
    result = int(input(" = "))
    return result

problem()
```